# how can design picker in android using adobe flex views

Tags: android, view, air, flexbuilder

*i am implementing adobe flex application in this application i am
using picker type view using adobe flex in adobe flex builder  how can
implement design in this view*
[image]

*please forwrad some suggestion i am new in adobe flex development*

thanks in advance

Narasimha

Comment: how can create uipickerview in flashbuilder tool using flex development please forward some suggestion

Comment: please help me in this question