# Adobe flex apk file not working in emulator displays only blankscreen how can resolve the issue?

Tags: android, apache-flex, adobe, emulation, flash-builder

i am developing adobe flex application using flashbuilder4.5 tool total app run configures desktop avd is working fine i am generate sign apk file this apk run in emulator its shows blank screen long time alreay install in this emulator adobe air also adobe air is working fine

how can resolve in this blank screen issue not working flex app apk in emulator

Thanks in advance

Narasimha

Comment: i have also same problem but we cant show flash content in emulator try device for testing purpose.

Comment: hi Dr.nik some youtube videos application running emulator its working fine

Comment: i dont knowbut same problem since from 6 month and no solution.

Comment: thank u very much u r response Dr.nik i am facing another problem in flash builder4.5 possible to create uipickerview see this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872826/how-can-design-picker-in-android-using-adobe-flex-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android `emulator` cant support **flash content** or `adobe air` base `apk`. so you need to check in real device.